# Calculating summations

Tags: algorithm, math

[Link to question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkWea.png)

I am struggling so answer the following question. I think the reason I am not doing it correctly is because i starts at 0 rather than 1, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: what is your question and what have you tried? can you show your code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum is equivalent to `3(n+1) + sum_{i=1}^n 2i`, [which is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) `3(n+1) + 2*n*(n+1)/2 = 3(n+1) + n(n+1) = (n+3)(n+1)`.

The result is thus `(n+3)(n+1)`. The whole derivation is [here](http://mathb.in/54583).

Comment: Yes. But I prefer the canonical form.

Comment: Fair enough, in which case I'd use (n + 3)(n + 1)